# AppEngine exec string gives SyntaxError

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Somehow, I'm getting the following error when executing a bit of source code that is stored in an AppEngine `db.TextProperty()`. It looks like there is a bit of indentation before the first statement, however, when I inspect the stored text, I can't see this. Also, I called `.strip()` on all the code  before storing it in the datastore

```
  File "...", line 208, in __init__
    exec(some_string, g)
  File "<string>", line 1
     class Agent(object):

^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any suggestions as to what else might cause this? Unicode conversions? Line endings? I'll update the question as I discover more.

Comment: No doubt you've considered this, but you should think *very* carefully about the security implications of allowing your app to execute code stored in datastore fields.

Comment: Yes, I don't think there is anything I can do, I'm allowing users to upload bits of python code and I'm executing them on the server. A) It's for a university course, so I know each of them personally, B) at least AppEngine still sandboxes the _whole_ app. But yes, it's going to be about as secure as a cardboard box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, turns out I had to do a simple line-ending replace on the code before storing it.

The AppEngine SDK doesn't complain about line-endings, but the production environment wants to have them normalized:

```
source = re.sub(r'(\r\n|\r|\n)', '\n', source)
```

Comment: Glad that was it. Another reason why exec of a string sometimes fails is that it is missing a trailing newline. I've come to append an extra \n just in case -- it never hurts...